# Terminated due to timeout error in java code in hackerrank program

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Problem(Hackerrank)
Given a base-10 integer, n, convert it to binary (base-2). Then find and print the base-10 integer denoting the maximum number of consecutive 1's in n's binary representation.

My Code is given below; which shows "RuntimeError"- and the compiler message is "Terminated due to timeout".

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=scn.nextInt();
        int rem = 0,s = 0,t = 0;
        while (n > 0)
            rem = n % 2;
            n = n / 2;
        if (rem == 1) 
        {
            s++;
            if (s >= t) 
                t = s;
            else
                s = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(t);
scn.close();
    }
}
```

Could you please help me to fix this error?

Comment: Your code takes too long to run, hence you need a more efficient way

Answer (score 3):

```
while (n > 0)
    rem = n % 2;
    n = n / 2;
```

Here, `n = n / 2` is outside the loop, so `n` will never change and this will be an infinite loop. That's why you get the timeout.

Change it to:

```
while (n > 0) {
    rem = n % 2;
    n = n / 2;
}
```

Hint: **Always** use braces. They'll ensure that multiple instructions are part of the `if`/`while`/whatever block and improve readability on single-instruction blocks.

Comment: Highly relevant is that if the OP had run it on her own computer, she would have observed the same behavior.